# Why does exportRoot not place movieclip on canvas using createjs and animate cc?

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs, animate-cc

I have created a movie clip called firework_mc in the library and wrote the following code hoping to place it on the canvas:

```
var movieClip = exportRoot.firework_mc.play();
movieClip.x=100;
movieClip.y=100;
```

I was hoping this would work but clearly not. Any other ideas on how to place it on the canvas?

Answer (score 1):

The `play` method [does not return a MovieClip instance](https://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/MovieClip.html#method_play). So your `movieclip` instance is null.

You should be able to do this:

```
var movieclip = exportRoot.firework_mc;
movieclip.play();
movieclip.x = 100;
movieclip.y = 100;
```

There are some issues with Animate export where children aren't immediately available for control. You can usually get around this with a `gotoAndStop` up front.

```
exportRoot.gotoAndStop(0);
// Then your code.
```

This will only work if `firework_mc` is a child of the exportRoot (ie, on the stage in Animate). If it isn't, you can access it in the animate lib:

```
var movieclip = new lib.firework_mc();
stage.addChild(movieclip);
// Or
exportRoot.addChild(movieclip);
```

Cheers,

Comment: I tried the following code out: var movieclip = new lib.firework_mc();
stage.addChild(movieclip);
movieclip.x = 100;
movieclip.y = 100; but it comes up with an error TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new lib.firework_mc()')

Comment: My sample assumes there is a symbol named "firework_mc" in the library.